# Problem populating Listview with FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to populate Listview with FirebaseAdaper. Data is populating correctly but I am seeing a few empty columns at the top. all the records are written from third column. I think i started seeing this after I deleted two records manually from firebase console real time database. Second issue is I am also trying to display the total number of records by using the "position" variable but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
ListView lv;
static int totalRecords;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    totalRecords = 0;

    final FirebaseListAdapter <Profile>adapter;

v = findViewById(R.id.listview);
lv.setAdapter(null);

String sPath = "/Customer/" ;
sPath = sPath.replaceAll("\\s", "");
if( database != null) {
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(sPath);
        Query query = myRef.orderByChild("/sTimeServiced/");

        if (query != null) {

                    totalRecords = 0;
                    FirebaseListOptions<Profile> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Profile>()
                                .setQuery(query, Profile.class)
                                .setLayout(android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item)
                                .setLifecycleOwner(this)   
                                .build();
                    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Profile>(options){


                             @Override
                                      protected void populateView(View view, Profile p, int position) {
                                           //    totalRecords = totalRecords + 1;
                                 TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.Count);
                                 tv.setText(Integer.toString(position));
                                              ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(p.sFN + " " + p.sLN + " (" + p.sTelephone + ")");
                                    }
                                  };
                              lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                              lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

Comment: Why don't you make your own adapter and pass the list to your adapter that came from your firebase database?

Comment: Show us your database structure.

Comment: {
  "Customer" : {
    "1111133" : {
      "sEmail" : "test12@yahoo.com",
      "sFN" : "test12",
      "sLN" : "testdfd",
      "sServices" : "Sample service",
      "sTelephone" : "1111133",
      "sTimeServiced" : "",
      "sTimeSignedIn" : "1561733441"
    }
  }
}

Comment: public static class Profile {
        public String sEmail;
        public String sFN;
        public String sLN;
        public String sServices;
        public String sTelephone;
        public String sTimeServiced;
        public String sTimeSignedIn;
        public String sPathToDocument;
        public String sMember;
        public String sReserved1; 
        public String sReserved2; 

    };

Comment: BTW I meant to say empty "rows" at the top not column. @ Sagar How is it going to help if I make custom adapter? I think the issue is some where else not the adapter. But again I am not certain.